# How does one do a qualified import in C?

Tags: c, import

Suppose I have a header file DS.h that contains some related data structures.

A

B (and importantly B is defined in terms of A)

Suppose I want to write another file Imp.c, that requires A and not B.  Is there a way to have Imp.c import just A and not B?

One solution, I suppose is to have two files: DSA.h and DSB.h; however, I am worried that if Imp2.c requires both datastructure B and Imp.c, then there will be some kind of error due to redefining A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the precompiler directive

```
#ifndef _FNAME_H  //If the compiler has not yet defined the variable
                  //_FNAME_H then define the functions in the header, else
                  //we do nothing
#define _FNAME_H

.... //Put definitions for the header file in here

#endif
```

This will stop any redefinition of functions / variables. See also the section on include guards [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can define a macros in your header file and set that macro using your .c File

```
#if USE_A
// A structure
#elif USE_B
// B structure
#endif
```